# UISearchDisplayController multiple separator lines when results are zero

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Working with UISearchDisplayController I found the following issue as show in image uploaded at [this URL](http://postimage.org/image/3zkrxl309/).

Default height of the row is 74, but when the results are zero, I don't whats happening but multiple separator lines appear.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     return 74;
}

   -(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadMySearchObjectsInBackground) withObject:nil];  
    return NO;
}

- (void) loadMySearchObjectsInBackground{
    NSString *searchStr=self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text;
    NSArray *foundItems;
    .....Code to fetch Result from Server.......
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
}
```

The above code works fine when results>0. But causes problem when foundItems count=0.

Any idea's to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
   if ([self.searchDataArray count] == 0) needSeparateCell = NO;
   else needSeparateCell = YES:
}
```

Set separatorSyteNone both in numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){
    if(!needSeparateCell) {
        [tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
    } else {
        [tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];
    }
}
```

Comment: Superb Answer. So, it means default row height when search has no results is 44.0. Any further explanation to it, please mention.

Comment: Just clear separate line when no results(no cells, don't need cell height)

Answer (score 2):

There is a very clean way to achieve this, if you don't need tableFooterView.

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];
```

This removes all separators below last cell. So if your tableView is empty, there will no separator lines at all.

It has worked for any kind of UITableView for me.